# ggvis line plot not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: r, internet-explorer, plot, ggvis

I have a ggvis plot with multiple lines. If I output in RStudio viewer, I get the correct graph, but if I run the same code in R and when the plot opens in Internet Explorer, the solid line is missing.

Below is the sample code I am working with

```
mydf <- data.frame(xval = c(1:5),USA = c(11:15), Canada = c(21:25), UK = c(31:35))

mydf2 <- tidyr::gather(mydf, 'var', 'val', -xval)

mydf2$mycol <- c(rep("Red",5), rep("Blue",5), rep("Green",5))
mydf2$mydash <- c(rep(5,5), rep(-1,5), rep(10,5))

myggv2 <- mydf2 %>% ggvis(x = ~xval, y = ~val, stroke = ~mycol,      
                      strokeDash := ~mydash) %>% layer_points(size := 100) %>%
  add_tooltip(function(d) { paste0("x:", d$xval, "<br>", "y:", d$val) }, "hover") %>% group_by(var) %>% 
  layer_paths() %>% add_axis("x", title = "qtrs") %>% 
add_axis("y", title = "MEV")%>% hide_legend("stroke")
myggv2
```

Below is the screenshot in Internet Explorer
[image: Internet Explorer Output]

and below is the screenshot in RStudio viewer
[image: RStudio Viewer Output]

Is it because Internet Explorer is not supported? Do you recommand any other browser where this will work.

P.S. This is a part of a larger shiny application I am developing and i would need a web interface for this.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Note that the plot is different if you switch the renderer (click on the gear icon) form SVG to canvas, it renders incorrectly in R-Studio then, but it renders differently in IE, in some ways better. Chrome behaves identically to R-Studio, so that is probably the best work-around if you need to use SVG render mode.